# SQL Query to add values from a column which have the same date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question that hopefully someone here can help me out with. I have a SQL table that looks a little like the table below, and what I am trying to do is to count add up the values and then have an output where each month is listed only once, with the added up values:

```
date                         value  

06/01/2020                     10          
06/01/2020                     20               
07/01/2020                     30 
07/01/2020                     20
07/01/2020                     20
08/01/2020                     40
08/01/2020                     30
09/01/2020                     10
09/01/2020                     20
```

so I am trying to write a query that would have an output like the following:

```
date                         value  

    06/01/2020                     30         
    07/01/2020                     70               
    08/01/2020                     70 
    09/01/2020                     30
```

I tried looking for a solution but unfortunatelly I couldnt find anything. I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Oh wow that was simpler than expected. Thanks for the help guys!